# Datatable : click on button does not open view

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, datatables

I have a datatable which displays overview data correctly.
I added a button which should go to my controller and from there open a new view displaying the details of the selected row.

The click works, I arrive at the method on my controller. But my details view doesn't open.

This is my javascript:

```
$("#search-logs tbody").on('click', 'button', function () {
    var self = this;
    var tr = $(self).closest('tr');
    var dtRow = datatable.row(tr[0]);
    var rowData = dtRow.data();
    var processId = rowData[0];

    $.get("@Url.Action("Details","Logs")", { id: processId });
});
```

And this is the code in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are calling an ajax get function, that is returning a View, instead of a simple HTTP response. To render this view, you need to redirect your page to that url, instead of doing an ajax request.

```
$("#search-logs tbody").on('click', 'button', function () {
    var self = this;
    var tr = $(self).closest('tr');
    var dtRow = datatable.row(tr[0]);
    var rowData = dtRow.data();
    var processId = rowData[0];

    location.href = '@Url.Action("Details","Logs")?id='+ processId;
});
```

Also if you still want to use get request, mostly to check if the id exists as it can return 404 Not found, you can the ajax function like this,

```
$("#search-logs tbody").on('click', 'button', function () {
    var self = this;
    var tr = $(self).closest('tr');
    var dtRow = datatable.row(tr[0]);
    var rowData = dtRow.data();
    var processId = rowData[0];

    $.get("@Url.Action("Details","Logs")", { id: processId }, 

    function(data, statusText, xhr){
     if(xhr.status == 200) location.href = '@Url.Action("Details","Logs")?id='+ processId;
    else alert('Sorry, this id does not exist');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
$("#search-logs tbody").on('click', 'button', function () {
   var self = this;
   var tr = $(self).closest('tr');
   var dtRow = datatable.row(tr[0]);
   var rowData = dtRow.data();
   var processId = rowData[0];
   location.href = '@Url.Action("Details","Logs")?id='+ processId;  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the constructed link in a new window or load in current window
//opens in new window

`window.open(newUrlCreated, '_blank');`

//opens in current window

1. `window.open(xhr.data);`
2. `window.location.href=newUrlCreated;`

   ```
   there are a lot of ways to achieve that.
   You can add an onclick="operate(row['info'], row['info'])" to your button which calls a function with specified data 
   from the datatable row, you will not bother to search for clicked button and row.
   ```

```
function operate(selectedRow, data, ...){
//logic of button for row
}
```